# Adding users to an LDAP group without ldap_mod_add()

Tags: php, ldap

The PHP function ldap_mod_add() is great for adding users to a group, like this:

```
$group_name = "CN=MyGroup,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com";
$group_info['member'] = $dn; // User's DN is added to group's 'member' array
ldap_mod_add($connect,$group_name,$group_info);
```

but this triggers a change at the attribute level as opposed to the object level, so it isn't detected and replicated to my mirror LDAP server.

**Is there, in PHP, any way to make this same operation using a object level function like ldap_modify()?**

Note: When I add it through Apache Directory Studio, it triggers the mirror operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ldap_modify` but you will need to provide the **complete** entry as third parameter.

I will need to check why `ldap_mod_add` does not trigger synchronisation in your setup.

Comment: But the problem with providing the complete entry is race conditions if two updates are called at (almost) the same time, isn't it?